# Can I put multiple, bootable MacOS installations on the same USB?

Tags: recovery

Back in the halcyon days of OS X 10.4 through 10.10, I used to have a USB stick that had several partitions each with a different version of OS X.  I could plug in the USB stick and option-boot, and up would come a menu letting me boot into any one of them.

Now, however, I see that OS X editions such as 10.14, 10.15 and 11.0 create *recovery partitions* as a mandatory and separate partition on the drive (that takes relatively little space).

Does this mean I am limited to one OS X installation per USB stick?

Answer (score 0):

The OS X installer deals with the recovery partition by partitioning the partition is given (from my understanding). If you only give it a 250 GB partition in a 500 GB disk, it will only use 248 GB (or something like that) for MacOS and 2 GB for recovery. Though I have not personally tried this, many articles explain that partitioning the disk into two APFS disks ***(this is NOT the same as creating an APFS volume that shares space in a container)***, which is similar to creating another partition dedicated to storing only files. Then, use the older/newer macos installer to install to the other partition (click show all disks when it asks to install on main partition). After installing, use startup disk picker or hold down option during bootup to boot on the older/newer version.

Comment: If the stick is big enough to hold two or more.

Answer (score 0):

I handle all OS X/macOS installers from Lion to Monterey on a single USB key , partitioned with eleven JHFS+ disks.
Installers needing to do their "own business" do it in a safe way within their own small created disk.
I never got any problem.
The trick is to give enough space to each of them according to the size of the installer, plus a little additional free space.

Comment: Those are installers.  I think OP is asking about installed systems ready to run.